# Java : Coming up with a unique number based on year and day of year

Tags: java

I am new to Java and wanted to get some suggestions regarding the problem that am trying to solve. I have to write a method that will generate an unique number.

So the unique number when represented in string will have 10 chars.

```
#1. First 2 will represent the YEAR
#2. Second 2 will represent the DAY OF YEAR
#3. Last 6 will represent a INCREMENTING digit which will reset at 12 AM midnight.
```

3 is what am confused with. I don't want to use any database or external files.

This will start at "000001" and keep incrementing until 11:59 PM at night
And at stroke of midnight it will reset to "000001"

Is there a efficient way of coding this?

My application is a server and it will be running 24x7 and the number generated is based on clients connected. And the 6 chars reserved for incremental counter is good enough and never supposed to exceed.

Comment: The server is just running in one instance? Does it matter if there are holes in the generated sequence?

Comment: Every client connection that calls a method in a Service will increment it.

Comment: Should it auto increment for every second or something should be called to increment it?

Comment: Maybe you could explain what you're trying to accomplish with this. As it is, I don't see why you wouldn't just use an existing [UUID](http://johannburkard.de/software/uuid/) package.

Comment: There are 365 or 366 days in a year.  The day field has to be 3 digits long.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc the OP is talking about characters, not digits. There are more than enough two character combinations.

Comment: @Stephen P: Lots of companies use a year, day, number or year, month, day, number combination as an invoice number.  Makes it easy to find historical invoices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a static variable in your class to be the counter. So as each client connects you increment the static int. You can have another static variable that holds the 'last updated' date. Just check the last updated date and if it is different than the current date you can reset the counter to 00001.

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the counter in a field of a class in your application.

Comment: That's easy! How to know when it's supposed to be reset back to "0"?

Comment: There are 1,440 minutes in a whole day (24 hours), so if your string represents minutes, then when it reaches 1,440, you will reset it. If it represents seconds, then it'd be 86,400 seconds.

Comment: @donguy76 If it's supposed to reset after midnight, keep another variable with the day number that was used for the last number generated. If that has changed, we must be in a new day, and thus the counter should reset to 0.